# Make calculation based on information provided

Tags: javascript

I am building a website and I want to do calculations based on information provided. I obviously need to have information provided in two out of the three fields to calculate the third's value.

The three fields are:

1. Price Per Gallon
2. Gallons Bought
3. Total Sale

I obviously know that I can calculate the amount of gas bought by dividing the `Total Sale` amount by the `Price Per Gallon`.

However I want to calculate based on whatever two fields are entered. I am trying to find out the best way to do this.

I know this much:

- Check to see which fields are empty
- Determine which type of calculation to make

Here is what I have so far:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id="totalSale" placeholder="Total Sale Amount" class="calculate" />
    <input type="number" id="gallonPrice" placeholder="Price Per Gallon" class="calculate" />
    <input type="number" id="gallons" placeholder="Gallons" class="calculate" />
</form>


<script>
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("calculate");

function calc(){
   var sale_amt = document.getElementById("totalSale");
   var ppg = document.getElementById("gallonPrice");
   var gallons = document.getElementById("gallons");
   if (sale_amt || ppg !== null) {
       var calc_gallons = sale_amt.value / ppg.value;
       gallons.value = calc_gallons.toFixed(3);
   }
}

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].addEventListener('keyup', calc, false);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `if (sale_amt || ppg !== null) {` oops - that's not right at all, as sale_amt will always be "truthy", so that piece of code will run regardless of what values are entered and what are not

Comment: the logic should take into consideration which element is currently being entered (that will be `this` in calc). Also, you need to take into consideration what happens when all three have values, and you change one ... which of the other two should be changed? ... e.g if you have gallons = 10, ppg = 5 so sale_amt will be 50. You say you can change any one ... so what happens if you change sale_amt to 60 - which of the other two elements needs to change? gallons->12 or ppg->6?

Comment: Basically I am just trying to make it easier for the user. They can enter whatever two pieces of information they feel like adding without entering the third. This information would probably only be entered once, and shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logic should take into consideration which element is currently being entered (that will be `this` in calc). Also, you need to take into consideration what happens when all three have values, and you change one ... which of the other two should be changed?

See if this works for you

```
var sale_amt = document.getElementById("totalSale");
var ppg = document.getElementById("gallonPrice");
var gallons = document.getElementById("gallons");

function calc(){
    var els = [sale_amt, ppg, gallons];
    var values = [sale_amt.value, ppg.value, gallons.value];
    var disabledElement = els.find(e=>e.disabled);
    var numValues = els.filter(e => e.value !== '' && !e.disabled).length;
    var calc_gallons = function() {
        gallons.value = (values[0] / values[1]).toFixed(3);
    };
    var calc_ppg = function() {
        ppg.value = (values[0] / values[2]).toFixed(3);
    };
    var calc_sale = function() {
        sale_amt.value = (values[1] * values[2]).toFixed(2);
    };
    if (numValues < 3) {
        if (numValues == 1 && disabledElement) {
            disabledElement.disabled = false;
            disabledElement.value = '';
            disabledElement = null;
        }
        els.forEach(e => e.disabled = e == disabledElement || (numValues == 2 && e.value === ''));
    }
    disabledElement = els.find(e=>e.disabled);

    switch((disabledElement && disabledElement.id) || '') {
    case 'totalSale': 
        calc_sale();
        break;
    case 'gallonPrice': 
        calc_ppg();
        break;
    case 'gallons':
        calc_gallons();
        break;
    }
}

var e = document.getElementsByClassName("calculate");
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].addEventListener('keyup', calc, false);
    e[i].addEventListener('change', calc, false);
}
```

Comment: I included the code in a Fiddle I created and it's not quite exactly what I'm looking for... 
For instance when entering the price per gallon, it automatically and randomly calculates a value. I haven't fully evaluated the code yet but I think that's because when declaring the variables you have `gallons_value = +ppg.value`. Maybe this should be `gallons.value`

Comment: I appreciate the help, and the effort. Do you think that's the most efficient way? I was thinking maybe a switch statement would be more practical. It's not really something I *need*, just something I want and let myself get distracted by.

Comment: `gallons_value = +ppg.value` = a typo on my part

Comment: the logic isn't clear cut especially when all three inputs have values, and you change the total ... which of the other two should change? when changing ppg and gallons, clearly the total should change ... the seemingly complex code is to cater for when 1, 2 or 3 inputs have values, and you are changing one of them

Comment: All three inputs shouldn't have values. The goal is to enter only two of the values and have the third calculated.

Comment: so, once there's data in the second input, whichever input is blank should be "read only"?

Comment: Wow! The code is way better, and does exactly what needed. I appreciate it, something to learn from. Great Example!
Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/euf77sos/2/